# Why execute command in docker container get different result with writing the command in Dockerfile?

Tags: java, docker, maven, dockerfile

Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:latest

COPY . /usr/src/myapp

WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp

RUN mvn compile && mvn clean install

EXPOSE 8000/tcp

CMD ["mvn", "exec:java", "-Dexec.mainClass='com.demo.App'", "-e"]
```

Execute `docker run -it --rm <image>` after build, project begins to build but it fails:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.8.2/maven-deploy-plugin-2.8.2.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.8.2/maven-deploy-plugin-2.8.2.pom (7.1 kB at 12 kB/s)
...
WARNING]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 'com.demo.App'
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.URLClassLoaderBuilder$ExecJavaClassLoader.loadClass (URLClassLoaderBuilder.java:198)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:520)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:271)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:833)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.898 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-11T09:41:54Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:java (default-cli) on project javasnippet: An exception occurred while executing the Java class. 'com.demo.App' -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:java (default-cli) on project javasnippet: An exception occurred while executing the Java class. 'com.demo.App'
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 'com.demo.App'
...
```

Then I comment out `CMD ["mvn", "exec:java", "-Dexec.mainClass='com.demo.App'", "-e"]` in Dockerfile which gives me:

```
FROM maven:latest

COPY . /usr/src/myapp

WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp

RUN mvn compile && mvn clean install

EXPOSE 8000/tcp

# CMD ["mvn", "exec:java", "-Dexec.mainClass='com.demo.App'", "-e"]
```

Build and run again `docker run -it --rm <image> bash`, get into the container:

```
root@c9ed5282e511:/usr/src/myapp# ls
Dockerfile  pom.xml  src  target
```

Then I execute `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass='com.demo.App' -e` to start the project, it works:

```
root@c9ed5282e511:/usr/src/myapp# mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass='com.demo.App' -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.8.2/maven-deploy-plugin-2.8.2.pom
...
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.3/commons-exec-1.3.jar (54 kB at 1.0 MB/s)
Server started at: Tue Apr 11 09:49:15 UTC 2023
```

Please guide me why this is happening and where am I doing wrong.

If any source code is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the single quotes inside the JSON-array-syntax `CMD` line

```bash
CMD ["mvn", "exec:java", "-Dexec.mainClass=com.demo.App", "-e"]
#                                          ^          ^ no single quotes
```

When you run this via a shell, the shell parser sees the single-quoted string, ignores the special meaning of any punctuation inside it, and removes the single quotes.  In a Docker exec-form command, none of this processing happens; the *only* escaping is what's necessary to make the command a valid JSON array.

This means in your original form the single quotes were passed on to the actual command.  You see that in the final exception, where Maven is trying to interpret a string (still including single quotes) as a Java class name.

Comment: That's it! It works for me. Accept my worship :X

Comment: [You see that in the final exception, where Maven is trying to interpret a string]

Not very familiar with maven's log format, new on this.

Comment: Compare the output with `mvn execJava  -Dexec.mainClass=a.random.class.Name -e`, and I suspect you will not see single quotes in that error message.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Need to be more careful.